# Why is Collection not simply treated as Collection<?>

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following API method taken from Shiro's [`org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/PrincipalCollection.html#fromRealm-java.lang.String-) interface but probably present in other libraries as well:

```
Collection fromRealm(String realmName);
```

*Yes even nowadays there are still libraries that are using raw-types, probably to preserve pre Java 1.5 compatibility?!*

If I now want to use this method together with streams or optionals like this:

```
principals.fromRealm(realmName).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I get a warning about unchecked conversion and using raw types and that I should prefer using parameterized types.

Eclipse:

> Type safety: The method collect(Collector) belongs to the raw type Stream. References to generic type Stream<T> should be parameterized

javac:

> Note: GenericsTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

As I can't change the API method's signature to get rid of this warning I can either annotate with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or simply cast to `Collection<?>` like this:

```
((Collection<?>) principals.fromRealm(realmName)).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As this cast of course always works I'm wondering why the compilers are not simply treating `Collection` as `Collection<?>` but warn about this situation. Adding the annotation or the cast doesn't improve the code a single bit, but decreases readability or might even shadow actual valid warnings about usage of unparameterized types.

Comment: The question mark type is a bit tricky. It can be anything, e.g. Collection<?> x; Collection<?> y; doesn't mean x can be cast to y, because it could be different. e. g. x = new ArrayList<String>() ; y=new ArrayList<Integer>() ;

Comment: Inserting `Collection<?>` in the place of `Collection` would be tantamount to saying "don't worry about raw types, I've got you covered", whereas developers *should* *actively* avoid raw types.

Comment: I checked their source code and the date when it was first released. They were actually using generic types at that time, but not for that method for some reasons..

Comment: `Collection` is not equivalent to `Collection<?>`, it's closer to `Collection<Object>`...

Comment: You can't insert anything into a `Collection<?>` because you don't know what the correct type is.

Comment: @immibis that’s a too strong statement. You can insert `null` into a `Collection<?>`. See alse [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514277/why-is-collection-not-simply-treated-as-collection#comment97767395_55514372)

Comment: I think this issue is particularly prominent when using raw type collections with Stream. In this case inserting is not an issue as you perform only read operations on the collection. That's why the problem is not so obvious compared to using raw type collections directly.

Comment: @dpr Indeed, the problem is that Java has no notion of “read only” constructs, so there is no way for the generic type system to behave differently for the Stream API. There are a few tweaks, however. Given a `Collection<?> c`, you can write `Collection<Object> c2 = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(c);` without problems, as the library designers incorporated the fact that they know, they prevent any attempt to insert an `Object` on the result, into the generic signature.

Comment: @Holger, yes something like a ReadOnlyCollection would be nice. But obviously not easy to add to Java.

Comment: I just noticed that “to preserve pre Java 1.5 compatibility” can not be the reason to use raw types here. That interface has two generic methods. And another method, `getRealmNames()` has been declared to return `Set<String>`.

Comment: @Holger yes I noticed that as well. Either they don't care or don't want to break code that relies on modifying the returned collection.

Comment: But old code, using raw types on the caller side, would continue to work, even if this interface was “generified”. That was the whole point of adding raw types to Generics, to allow both sides to evolve independently without breaking compatibility.

Comment: @Holger of course, if they would have used `Collection<Object>` you're right. Then they don't care :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The reason is quite simple:

You may read `Object`s from a `Collection<?>` the same way as from `Collection`. **But** you can't add `Object`s to a `Collection<?>` (The compiler forbids this) whereas to a `Collection` you can.

If after the release of Java 5 the compiler had translated every `Collection` to `Collection<?>`, then previously written code would not compile anymore and thus would destroy the backward compatibility.

Comment: To add to this: `Collection<?>` is _not_ "a Collection of any types." It's "a Collection of some type, but that type is unknown." That's why you can't add non-null objects to it: the compiler is trying to tell you that to add those objects, you'd have to know that the Collection's `<T>` is a superclass of those objects (whereas you don't actually know anything about `T`, since you typed the Collection to `<?>`).

Comment: Just to prevent the impression that `Collection<?>` was kind of immutable: you can add `null` to a `Collection<?>`, further, you can pass a `Collection<?>` to a generic method expecting a `Collection<T>`, which then may add elements of type `T`, i.e. duplicates of elements already in the collection. As a practical example, you can invoke `Collections.swap(list, ix1, ix2)` with a `List<?>`. And, of course, removing elements always works. But you can not add an arbitrary `Object` to it like with the raw typed `Collection`.

Comment: FWIW: I think Scala's syntax for existential types may also help to understand the meaning of `Collection<?>`. Scala's equivalent of this is `Collection[_]`. And this is shorthand for `Collection[T] forSome { type T }`. The latter should be understood as _This is a collection of instances of `T`. There is some specific type which is equal to T but which one is not known at this location in the code_.

Answer (score 21):

The major difference between raw type and unbounded wildcard `<?>` is that the latter is *type safe*, that is, on a compile level, it checks whether the items in the collection are of the same type. Compiler won't allow you to add string and integer to the collection of wildcard type, but it *will* allow you to do this:

```
List raw = new ArrayList();
raw.add("");
raw.add(1);
```

Actually, in case of *unbounded* wildcard collections (`List<?> wildcard = new ArrayList<String>()`), you can't add anything at all to the list but `null` (from [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)):

> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?, it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.

Comment: "the [unbounded wildcard <?>] is type safe, that is, on a compile level, it checks whether the items in the collection are of the same type." - Huh?! This is in contradiction to the rest of your answer. - Or maybe not quite; one could say that it *is* type safe in that it disallows *any* objects to be put into a collection of `<?>`.

Comment: The compiler performs no checks at all on what is *in* a generic collection.  Rather, it performs checks on the (declared) types of the arguments to its constructors and methods, and on the expectations of the types of its methods' return values.

Answer (score 8):

A `Collection<?>` screams:

> Please don't add anything to me. I have a strict content type, ... well uh, I just forgot what type it is.

While a `Collection` says:

> It's all cool ! You can add whatever you like, I have no restrictions.

So, why shouldn't the compiler translate `Collection` to `Collection<?>` ?
Because it would put up a lot of restrictions.

Comment: I really like this explanation, very basic, but on point and easily understandable +1 :)

Comment: Having said all that :) , An untyped `Collection` is actually more like a `Collection<Object>`. And you could in fact replace all legacy `Collection` usages with `Collection<Object>` as long as they haven't been replaced with more precise types (e.g. If you replace one usage with `Collection<String>` and another with `Collection<Object>` then again, you may break stuff).

Answer (score 3):

A use-case that I can think of as to why `Collection` is not considered as `Collection<?>` is let say we have a instance of `ArrayList`

Now if the instance is of type `ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<Double>` or `ArrayList<String>`, you can add that type only(type checking). `ArrayList<?>` is not equivalent to `ArrayList<Object>`.

But with only `ArrayList`, you can add object of any type. This may be one of the reason why compiler is not considering `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<?>` (type checking).

One more reason could be backward compatibility with Java version that didn't have generics.