# The intersection of Java generics and Scala is...not going well

Tags: java, scala, generics

I freely admit to being a little out of my depth here. My formal training in type systems is a good few decades behind me. I’ve used generics in Java rather trivially once or twice, but they’re not something about which I can claim to have a deep and thorough understanding. I’m also a relative newcomer to Scala, so I’m not claiming a deep or thorough understanding of its type system either.

I set out to update my XML Calabash v2 implementation, written in Scala (2.12 today) to use Saxon 9.9. Saxon 9.9 introduces generics in a number of places. Fine by me. I can cope, I imagine.

Except, I can’t apparently.

The stumbling block is trying to implement a class that extends the ExtensionFunctionDefinition class. It has an inner class that extends the ExtensionFunctionCall class. That, in turn, has an abstract method, call, defined thusly in Java:

```
public abstract Sequence<?> call(
    XPathContext context,
    Sequence[] arguments
)
```

My first attempt to define this in Scala was:

```
override def call(
    context: XPathContext,
    arguments: Array[Sequence]
): Sequence[_]
```

but that doesn’t compile: “trait Sequence takes type parameters”.

Which is true:

```
public interface Sequence<T extends Item<?>>
```

(Item, btw, is:

```
public interface Item<T extends Item<?>>
extends GroundedValue<T>
```

which I find slightly confusing for other reasons)

For my second attempt, I tried:

```
override def call(
    context: XPathContext,
    arguments: Array[Sequence[_]]
): Sequence[_]
```

But that, I’m told, doesn’t override anything. Hark, the compiler says:

```
[error] (Note that Array[net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence]
does not match Array[net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence[_]]:
their type parameters differ)
```

And here we seem to be at an impasse. I can just implement the damned thing in Java, of course, but is this an actual limitation in Scala or in my understanding?

I was lying before, by the way, about my first attempt. My first attempt was actually:

```
override def call(
    context: XPathContext,
    arguments: Array[Sequence[_ <: Item[_ <: Item[_]]]]
): Sequence[_ <: Item[_ <: Item[_]]]
```

which I crafted by bluntly copying Java into Scala and letting IntelliJ IDEA translate it. I had failed to work out what to do with the recursive nature of the Item declaration.

Comment: Another question about [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514277/why-is-collection-not-simply-treated-as-collection) is currently in the Hot Questions. What a strange coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
override def call(context: XPathContext, arguments: Array[Sequence[_ <: Item[_]]]): Sequence[_] = ???
```

Comment: That's unsuccessful: (Note that Array[net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence[_]] does not match
Array[net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence[_ <: net.sf.saxon.om.Item[_]]]:
their type parameters differ)

Comment: @Norm it compiles https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/7d7e67274061f90572d63672e67e09e6

Comment: @Norm in some sense they do match. You can check that `implicitly[Array[Sequence[_ <: Item[_]]] =:= Array[Sequence[_]]]`
 `implicitly[Array[Sequence[_]] =:= Array[Sequence[_ <: Item[_]]]]` compile.

Answer (score 3):

This here definitely compiles (and thereby confirms that Dmytro Mitin's proposal works):

```
// ExtensionFunctionCall.java
public interface ExtensionFunctionCall {
  Sequence<?> call(String ctx, Sequence[] args);
}

// Item.java
public interface Item<T extends Item<?>> {}

// Sequence.java
public interface Sequence<T extends Item<?>> {}

// Impl.scala
class Impl extends ExtensionFunctionCall {
  override def call(
    ctx: String,
    args: Array[Sequence[_ <: Item[_]]]
  ): Sequence[_] = ???
}
```

By the way, it's not just Scala's problem. If you forget Scala for a second, and try to implement it in Java, you get essentially the same errors:

```
class ImplJava implements ExtensionFunctionCall {
  public Sequence<?> call(
    String ctx,
    Sequence<?>[] args
  ) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

gives:

```
ImplJava.java:1: error: ImplJava is not abstract and does not override abstract method call(String,Sequence[]) in ExtensionFunctionCall
class ImplJava implements ExtensionFunctionCall {
^
ImplJava.java:2: error: name clash: call(String,Sequence<?>[]) in ImplJava and call(String,Sequence[]) in ExtensionFunctionCall have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
  public Sequence<?> call(
                     ^
2 errors
```

Now, this is really mystifying, I have no idea how to write down this type in Java. I'm not sure whether it's even expressible in Java without reverting to 1.4-style. The `Sequence[]` thing is just evil, or, to quote [this wonderful article linked by Dmytro Mitin](https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/02/26/rawtypes.html):

> Raw Types are bad. Stop using them

Comment: For context, this works fine in Java in my context:  public Sequence<?> call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments)

Comment: @Norm My problem is that there are seemingly two separate concepts: `Sequence` and `Sequence<?>`, which are completely incompatible and not mutually interchangeable, and which are both mapped to Scala's existential types in some strange way. I wasn't even aware that there were *two* families of Java types which are both mapped to Scala's existentials. I was certain that after Java 1.4 the old erased generics became mere syntactic sugar for something that is expressible by wildcards, but this is not the case, apparently.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the very handy link. I have no control over the Java library, though I've passed the link along. In the meantime, I wrote some Java shim code.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You can avoid raw types not always. For example because of higher-kinded types in Scala absent in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528032/how-to-export-scala-transformation-to-java/

Answer (score 0):

I think `Sequence` with no type parameters in java translates into `Sequence[Foo]` where `Foo` is the highest possible super-type (`Item` in this case). 
So, I would expect something like this to work:

```
override def call(context: XPathContext, arguments: Array[Sequence[Item[_]]]): Sequence[_] = ???
```

Comment: No, this doesn't compile: `Error:(6, 14) method call overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of object App contain the following, non final members named call:
def call(x$1: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathContext,x$2: Array[App_1.Sequence]): App_1.Sequence[_]
override def call(context: XPathContext, arguments: Array[Sequence[Item[_]]]): Sequence[_] = ???`.

Comment: Yep, this one appears not to override either of the definitions of call.